# Care to be taken when serving static content (JS, CSS, Media) from different domain?

Tags: cookieless, static-content

Let me try to explain by example. Say website is hosted at `example.com` (NOT `www.example.com`). In order to serve static content cookie-free, I've chosen to use a different domain `example-static.com`.

Now, lets consider that my static content is currently served like this:

```
http://example.com/js/script.js
http://example.com/css/style.css
http://example.com/media/image.jpg
```

** Now I create a CNAME record aliasing `example-static.com` to my main domain i.e. `example.com` so that the static content is served as such:

```
http://example-static.com/js/script.js
http://example-static.com/css/style.css
http://example-static.com/media/image.jpg
```

** Is that all I have to do? Will ***all*** browsers execute JavaScript files and load web fonts without any security concerns? OR should I be using some .htaccess rules to modify header information and the like?

**PS:** It would be great if you can provide what rules should be added, if need be.

**EDIT:** The reason why I added a bounty to this question is that people I know have advised me against serving JS from a different domain. They aren't able to give me a clear explanation either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work without extra config. However: does it worth the pain? If you use some real content delivery network that's fine, but simply faking one, to be cookie-free? A much better approach would be to minimize cookie size IMHO.

Comment: I need to use an extra cookie in comment form to prevent spam. So, yeah, in my case it's worth the pain.

Comment: I see. In that case the answer still holds: it'll work without any issues. (well, we can't be **really** sure about IE ever, can we? :) )

Answer (score 0):

Gergely's answer answers my question. And I've also found an alternative. Since my website is served from `example.com`, instead of serving static content from a different domain, I am planning to serve the `cookies` themselves from a different sub-domain `www.example.com`.

Simple, and should do the job.

Comment: another option is to use cookiepath to limit the cookies to smthing like: docroot/dynamiccontent, while putting the static stuff in docroot/static or similiar

Comment: on the cookie size: i had to tinker with that kinda optimization, and was shocked when i found out that the average cookie size in the client-requests were smaller than the referrer header for example. I just accepted the fact that adding 100 bytes to every HTTP request is not a big deal. (actually there's one exception: if those extra bytes will make the client request bigger than the average MTU (1500 or 1492 bytes for *DSL users) that's a big hit. It means the client has to send two packets instead of one.)

Comment: @GergelySzilagyi And you've received +100 now :)